# How to post message on facebook page via a user

Tags: facebook, api

I have an facebook application in my website. i want to publish a user's profile link and some other stuff to my facebook page automatically. But currently this is being posted via page admin not user. How i can fix it?

Comment: By using a user access token instead of a page access token.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I tries passing the user access token like CBroe said, but it still shows up as the Page itself and not the user. I've even tried through the Graph API Explorer and not my app and I got the same thing. I think it's a bug.